# add a new column from client side in KX

Tags: kdb

I have a table in server like this

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  
-----------------------------
42034 64878 62076 3716  51556 
76279 27763 61893 56680 34261
54345 39819 44585 42108 83936 
88150 17032 58679 35727 56002 
22830 77292 56069 58333 31837
```

I try to add a new column from the client-side by using one of the existing column +1.user will input the existing column number.

```
#cat add_cols.q

N:.z.x
h: hopen 5010;
h "update newcol1:N+1 from `t"
res:h "t";
show res
exit 1
#q ./add_cols.q col1
```

The result as

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  newcol1
-------------------------------------
42034 64878 62076 3716  51556 6
76279 27763 61893 56680 34261 6
54345 39819 44585 42108 83936 6
88150 17032 58679 35727 56002 6
22830 77292 56069 58333 31837 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h "update newcol1:N+1 from `t"
```

This will not work as it will use whatever N is defined as on the server process which must be 5.

You want something like this:

```
//so.q
N:.Q.opt[.z.x]; // better to use flags and convert into a dictionary with .Q.opt
h:hopen 5010;
h raze "update newcol1:",N[`myCol],"+1 from `t";
show h"t";
exit 0; // generally anything other than exit 0 indicates a failure in execution

// creilly solution - avoids the user from feeding problematic code to the server process
N:.Q.opt[.z.x]; h:hopen 5010;
col:first`$N`myCol; 
h(!;`t;();0b;enlist[`newCol1]!enlist(+;col;1));
show h"t"; exit 0;

// This could also be defined on the server as a function e.g.:
myFunc:{[col] ![`t;();0b;enlist[`newCol1]!enlist(+;col;1)] }
// And called from the client with h(`myFunc;col)


q so.q -myCol col1
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 newcol1
--------------------------------
370  45   804  829  660  46
481  851  12   503  926  852
564  487  481  120  418  488
578  94   732  710  126  95
920  392  995  506  77   393

t:([]col0:5?1000;col1:5?1000;col2:5?1000;col3:5?1000;col4:5?1000)
```

Comment: Hi Helen, please be careful if exposing this method to users, as it is liable to code injection e.g. `q so.q -myCol "col2 from t;.cr.t:2;.z.w(show;.cr.t);exit 0; //"`
As a bare minimum, either validate the user input and reject any bad queries or use a prepared functional select in place of qsql e.g. `col:first`$N`myCol; h(!;`t;();0b;enlist[`newCol1]!enlist(+;col;1))` instead of `h raze "update newcol1:",N[`myCol],"+1 from `t"` . You can read more on functional selects here - https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

Comment: Correct formatting below:
`col:first\`$N\`myCol;
h(!;\`t;();0b;enlist[\`newCol1]!enlist(+;col;1))`